# Posting a multipart form with file in Axios, Nodejs

Tags: node.js, http, axios

```
const form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append("File", fs.createReadStream(pathToFile));
form_data.append('Login', alias.toUpperCase());

const request_config = {
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic 123",
        "Content-Type": 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    data: form_data
};

await axios.post(url, params, request_config).then(response => {
```

Posting to an endpoint I can't debug. The response is a 500.

This is the error:

[image]

Is this the correct way do it?

Can I somehow see exactly what Axios is sending?

This is a postman request I received from the author of the API. This passes:

```
POST /api/upload HTTP/1.1

Host: api.test.contoso.se

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

Authorization: Basic 123

User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.13.0

Accept: */*

Cache-Control: no-cache

Postman-Token: 089af753-fa12-46c4-326f-dfc39c36faab,c5977145-ece3-4b53-93ff-057788eb0dcf

Host: api.test.contoso.se

accept-encoding: gzip, deflate

content-length: 18354

Connection: keep-alive

cache-control: no-cache

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Lang"

SV
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="File"; filename="/C:/Users/file.docx


------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Login"

ABC
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message in your screenshot is clear: "Missing content-type boundary".

To use axios for `multipart/form-data` request, you need to set boundary to upload the file. Example code is:

```
const form_data = new FormData();

...

const request_config = {
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic 123",
        "Content-Type": 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + form._boundary
    },
    data: form_data
};

await axios.post(...)
```

*"Can I somehow see exactly what Axios is sending?"*

You can use HTTP proxy software such as Charles to intercept the request, and check what data is sent.

Comment: Info for readers: for NodeJS, if you're using require("form-data"), it's not `form._boundary`but `form_data.getBoundary()`

Comment: More intuitive way would be to set the headers which are automatically created by the FormData object by `data: form_data.getHeaders()`. This will set the Content-type header with values & no need to set it manually. Ref - https://github.com/form-data/form-data#axios

Comment: Working with TypeScript, properties `_boundary` nor the method `.getHeaders()` exist on type `FormData`